# What do grayed out flags mean in the 10k tools?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

**Refer to this image:**

---

> [image]

---

Why is the top "not an answer" flag gray, while the bottom one is not? I have been noticing this happen a lot in the 10k tools, and it seems to be inconsistent. I haven't been able to notice anything in common with the posts with the grayed out flags.

<sup>(I have also noticed that the only difference between the grayed out and normal flags in the HTML is that the gray ones have the `.blur` CSS class.)</sup>

---

In reply to [George Stocker♦'s answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193987/180276):

> I always thought it was because the flag surrounding that post had already been handled by someone (be it a moderator or someone else), so it's considered a 'historical flag' on that post.

Well if it's already handled, then why is it in the 10k tools in the first place?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the flag weight of the flag(s)?

Comment: Grayed out flags are flags that have already been handled in the past. The only question is what the *current* flag is that makes it show up in the tools, or if that's just put together with the other NAA flags here.

Comment: @Doorknob I updated my post with why it's showing up in the queue again.

Comment: The initial flag date on this flag is "Feb 16", which sugests it was handled months ago. Considering it wasn't deleted, I assume someone invalidated it (or maybe it was just dismissed by a mod?). Maybe it's grayed because it was originally dismissed without action in February, and then resurfaced because someone else flagged it recently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gray flags are flags that have been raised on a post in the past, and are shown to you for context. The other indicates current, pending flags.

You don't see these as often, but when you see posts that are repeatedly flagged in the same manner over time it's worth looking at. In this case you can draw the following picture:

- Someone flagged this as NAA back on Feb 16, no action was taken
- Someone else is flagging the same way today

*Something* about that answer makes people say that it doesn't qualify as an answer, yet others obviously find some kind of value in it, or disagree altogether.

If you see this happen, especially for NAA (not an answer), you've got one of two choices to make if you want to take action:

1. Do you agree? Go ahead and add your flag
2. Do you *disagree*? Please, figure out what about that answer keeps tripping this flag and edit / suggest an edit to fix whatever that is, so this cycle stops

In any event, that's the distinction. The context is also important, as it's a very good use case of why we display old flags for historical context.

Comment: I seem to remember the same type of flag being broken up by handled and unhandled (at least, that's how it used to show up in the mod queue). Has that changed? I assume it changed when Jarrod did his flag queue work.

Comment: Okay, so [this one](http://i.imgur.com/GYyDSqn.png) means that 1 person flagged as VLQ, it was declined, and now someone's flagging as NAA. Correct?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker There's some unfinished business in the 10k queue that we have to handle yet, some open bugs blocked by finishing those changes up (as I understand it)

Comment: @Doorknob Don't think 'declined', just no action was taken (the flag may have been validated). But yes, that's the gist of it.

Comment: @TimPost So then why aren't the flags broken down when they're the same type?

Comment: @Doorknob that's one of the quirks I alluded to when replying to George, a few things need to be fixed up in that particular view.

Comment: @TimPost Okay then. I have [reported this as a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193991/180276).

Answer (score 3):

I always thought it was because the flag surrounding that post had already been handled by someone (be it a moderator or someone else), so it's considered a 'historical flag' on that post.

After looking at the flags [on the post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9181745/16587), it has recently been flagged as 'not an answer' (recent being in the last few days).  That's why it's in your queue.

A number of those '5' flags are recent flag, with some of those flags being older. My guess is that because all the flags are the same, the system (recently?) decided not to show the following:

```
not an answer - Feb 16th (greyed out)
not an answer x3 - recent
```

This could possibly be a bug related to the recent changes in the flag queue, or it could be new desired behavior. I do know that the behavior used to be different: There'd be greyed out flags that had been handled, and new flags (even for the same reason) would be separately listed and not grey.

The question really is, do you agree with that flag or not? :-)

Comment: If it's already handled, then why is it in the 10k tools in the first place?

Comment: @Doorknob I have suppositions, but not answers to that question. I only know what that behavior means, not why it happens. I'll punt this to Tim Post to look at.

Comment: So wait, does that mean there were 4 previous NAA flags that were marked helpful, then someone re-flagged it?

Comment: @Doorknob No. They were declined. I have the specific number, but let's just say more than 1 was  declined and more than 1 reflagged it (I'm not entirely sure how much information I can give out since the system no longer breaks it down for regular 10K users).

Comment: So it used to break it down? When was it changed? Are there any meta posts referencing this?

Comment: Okay, so [this one](http://i.imgur.com/GYyDSqn.png) means that 1 person flagged as VLQ, it was declined, and now someone's flagging as NAA. Correct?

Comment: @Doorknob That means there are two flags. One active, one 'handled' (where handled can mean 'helpful', 'declined', or 'disputed'). The handled flag is greyed out in your example. Here is the post your picture is of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18335480/16587

Comment: Why do you show the handled flag at all? It seems to be mostly irrelevant. Also, if the flags are of the same type all of them appear to be handled. Furthermore this isn't explained anywhere really so it's confusing. (by the way I know which post it is; I took that screenshot :P)

Comment: @Doorknob I don't believe it's irrelevant. It's good context.  I use that context as a moderator with almost every post I look at.  The fact that flags of the same type are now lumped together seems to be a behavior change that (barring someone from SE inc saying it isn't) I view as a bug, and I distinctly remember it not being like that previously.

Comment: Okay, I will now make a meta post reporting this bug then. I also think that this should be explained somewhere, so that users know what it means. (the 10k privileges page maybe)