# Eeek! Handled and unhandled flags are not broken down when they're of the same type

Tags: bug, 10k-tools

I recently learned that [if a post is flagged, and the flag is handled, and then the post is reflagged, the handled flags will show up grayed out in the 10k tools.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193986/180276)

[image]

However, if a post is flagged as NAA, for example, and the flag is handled, then the post is reflagged as NAA, the handled and unhandled flags are merged together:

[image]

Comment: Is there some sort of reason that you need to see them unmerged? If so, you might want to explain that.

Comment: @animuson It's a bug - it's telling me that all of the flags have been handled even though some haven't been. Also, consistency.

Comment: To me it's just saying that a flag of that type has been handled before. Of all the time I've spent in the 10k tools and as a moderator, I've never really cared about it. How will unmerging those help you in determining how you're going to process that item? For me, it would just add extra text on the screen that I don't really need to see.

Comment: @animuson It would tell me how many flags were already handled and how many there are currently.

Comment: But why is that information useful at all? Knowing how they were handled or why they were handled a certain way is much more useful information than how many flags were handled previously.

Comment: FWIW, in the mod dashboard the name(s) of the flaggers are displayed as well - with shading used to indicate which flaggers' flags have already been handled. Since those are omitted from the 10k tools, the information on how many flags are new is lost. We're doing some heavy reworking of this whole thing right now anyway, so stay tuned.